# Is it possible to use older facebook APIs in an app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, api

Is it possible to use an older Facebook Graph API to fetch a user's friends' data (i.e. name, birthday & profile picture)?

Comment: Do you mean older than the last available? Check: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions

Comment: Old apps can use API v1.0 until 4/30/2015 but after that they will have to use API v2.0 or later which you can not get the things you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not recommended because in facebook sdk docs it is clearly written

The current, latest version of the Graph API is v2.2. Apps calling v1.0 have until April 30, 2015 to upgrade to v2.0 or later.

To prevent broken experiences for people using your app, we strongly recomment you upgrade your apps to the latest current version at the earliest opportunity. Your app might not work after next month.

Answer (score 0):

**Only Apps created before end of April 2014 can use v1.0 of the Graph API.** Every App created after April 2014 can only use v2.x, so there is no way to get friend data in those.

Also, v1.0 will be gone for good after April 2015, even old Apps will not be able to use it after that.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog